# Zurb Foundation 5 offcanvas not working

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to implement an offcanvas to a site using zurb's foundation framework, for mobile viewing, and just copied the code for it from the documentation, but it just doesn't work.

the code is the following:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--offcanvas begin-->
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap">
        <div class="inner-wrap">

            <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small">
                <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
                    <span>Foundation</span>
                </a>  
            </nav>


            <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                    <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The test!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <section class="main-section">
            <!--offcanvas begin-page-content-->

                <!--content-->

            <!--offcanvas end-page-content-->
            </section>

            <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

        </div><!--inner-wrap-->
    </div><!-- off-canvas-wrap -->
<!--offcanvas end-->
</body>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ribena's answer is not working anymore, at version 5.2.3, though it was at version 5.0.3.

For it to work now, the trigger javascript needs to be put:

- or at the end of the `<body>` tag as it said in the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html), like Daniel said
- or inside the `<head>` this way (using JQuery):

`<script>
        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            $(document).foundation();
        });
    </script>`

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem.  The <strong>OR</strong> may not have been strong enough, took me several tries to finally move the code to the head of the document.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In some instances this can be fixed by supplying the HTML data attribute `data-offcanvas`

```
  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
```

See this fiddle for the working changes to your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/vooaqtxt/

Comment: After trying all the other answers this is the one I found that made the difference between 5.2.2 and 5.2.3

Comment: This is the correct answer. Fixed it for version 5.5.2

Answer (score 3):

I have replicated the problem, and found that moving `jquery`, `foundation.min.js` resources and the initialization call:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

to just before the closing `</body>` tag fixed the problem (leave `modernizr.js` in the head).

**Edit:** As @Jigar pointed out `offcanvas.js` does not need to be loaded externally.

**p.s.** In just about every case, [it's best to place all your script references at the end of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer), just before `</body>`

Comment: `offcanvas.js` is included in `foundation.min.js` so loading it seperately is not required

Comment: This should no longer be necessary with Foundation 5.0.3!

Answer (score 1):

Update to Foundation 5.0.3 and your code should work fine again.

Answer (score 1):

#### You are missing the href="#" on your toggle button link

If the href="#" is missing, it will not work on mobile devices.

#### This is what your nav should look like:

```
<nav class="tab-bar show-for-small">
    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#">
        <span>Foundation</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```