# Where to put jQuery when using Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), and from the author's [examples](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#events), the author placed jQuery in the header and javascript right after the datetime inputs.

However, I read some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer)  suggesting that all scripts should be loaded last. But if I placed jQuery last, the datetimepickers will not work (since jQuery was not loaded, a

> javascript uncaught referenceerror

will be reported).

I'm just wondering what is the best practice in using Bootstrap datetimepicker??

Comment: Add your code here and in a JSFIDDLE/StackSnippet. It would be helpful.

Comment: the order of the scripts must be maintained, regardless of where in the page you include them. it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dpStartDate').data({date: '2014-10-22'});
$('#dpStartDate').datepicker('update');
$('#dpStartDate').datepicker().children('input').val('2014-10-22');
```

set the calendar date on propertie data-date
update (required)
set the input value (remember the input is child of datepicker).
this way you are setting the date to '2014-10-22'