# In Shiny for R, why does Sys.Date() return yesterday's date inside a dateInput?

Tags: r, date, input, shiny

I have a `dateInput` in my `ui.R` as follows:

```
dateInput("asOfDateTime", label = "As Of", value = Sys.Date(), max = Sys.Date())
```

For `2015-05-15`, this gives the `dateInput` a default value of `2015-05-14`.

However, when I run `Sys.Date()` in the console on `2015-05-15`, I get the correct value: `2015-05-15`.

Why does Shiny give yesterday's date inside my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does sound weird. I am just starting on Shiny so do not know for sure.

**COULD IT BE**

1. **Timezone??** Maybe `Sys.timezone()` is different on their servers?

   Have you tried formatting the date for your timezone?
2. **Caching problem??**

   Could the value be cached from an old instance? But I take it you are running this within your Shinyserver{ ... code} not above.  Try a rebuild in the Dashboard?

**BUT HERE IS SOLUTION**

Set `value` to `NULL` ([see helpfile](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateInput.html))

> value The starting date. Either a Date object, or a string in yyyy-mm-dd format. If NULL (the default), will use the current date in the client's time zone.

It will default to your date in your timezone.

```
dateInput("asOfDateTime", label = "As Of", 
                                    value = NULL, max = Sys.Date())
```

gave me today's date

[image: ShinyDateInputEG]

Comment: 1. My time-zone is set correctly (`GMT`). 2. It is inside a `shinyUI` call.