# Sys.Date() shows wrong date in shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny

This code should show me yesterday as date for start and end with today as the last option.
It worked for several month, I did not change anything, but since some weeks I get the wrong date.

It shows me the day before yesterday if I run this code locally, rstudio on my ubuntu server or connect to shiny server running this code.

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')

shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    dateRangeInput("daterange", "Daterange",start = Sys.Date()-1
                   ,end = Sys.Date()-1,max=Sys.Date())
  ),
  server <- function(input,output){}
)
```

I found this question, [In Shiny for R, why does Sys.Date() return yesterday's date inside a dateInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254875/in-shiny-for-r-why-does-sys-date-return-yesterdays-date-inside-a-dateinput), and 
with start=NULL,end=NULL I get correctly today, but as I need yesterday this is no solution for me.

If I run Sys.Date() in the console it gives me the right date, locally and on my server. The problem only occurs if I run this as a shiny app.

---

### Update 21.10.2015

I tried a bit around thanks to Oskar Forsmo's suggestion to get system("date") inside the app, which gives me the correct date and time.

And it gets even more strange:

```
library(shiny)

values <- reactiveValues()

shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    uiOutput("timerange"),
    textOutput( "today" )

  ),
  server <- function(input,output){

    isolate(values$day <- Sys.Date())

    output$today <- renderText({
      as.character(values$day-1)
    })

   output$timerange <- renderUI({ dateRangeInput("daterange", "Daterange",start = values$day-1
                   ,end = values$day-1,max=values$day) })

  })
```

In the output object "today" I have the correct date, in the uiOutput "timerange" I have the wrong day, it shows again the day before yesterday.

I'm gonna provide a screenshot, because I would not believe myself.

[wrong day in dateRangeInput, right in textOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6hwX.jpg)

And on top of that, the app run on shiny server shows the correct time/date to some of my collegues and some get the same wrong date.

To isolate the error, as I have the correct day in renderText there must be a problem somewhere with the dateRangeInput object which is triggered by my desktop?!

---

### Update 29.10.2015

I did not change anything on the code/server but it shows now the correct date, have no idea why but it works as of today.. if anybody have an idea why this happens i would really appreciate to know.

Comment: have you tried setting the timezone in /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron?

Comment: Check this `Sys.timezone()`

Comment: I set the timezone right now in /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron/Renviron.site with the line 'TZ = "GMT" ' - I tried GMT, CET and CEST. Sys.timezone() shows the set value in RStudio, but the problem remains.

Comment: I just checked the date on the ubuntu server, it is correctly set to CEST. I'm really confused right now, doesn't seem to be a timezone problem. I even have this behaviour on my windows desktop as stated above.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't have a clue on what's causing this. Out of curiosity what happens if you get the date by `system("date")` from inside the shiny app?

Comment: I'm having the same behavior on Mac. Where if I run a date convert in console it is correct. When I run it from shiny running on the same machine in the same R session I get the wrong date. This is the same code. I think shiny has a default to UTC somewhere.

Comment: Also look at this answer on SO [Get the user's current date and time in R/Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710333/10489562)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it was due to local timezone being different than the server timezone. I was able to get the correct date to appear when I converted each date to a POSIX date (which includes time zone). If you want shiny to display the original format created by `Sys.Date()`, you will also have to use the `format` parameter.

Here is working code:

```
dateRangeInput("daterange", "Daterange", start = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()-1),
              end = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()-1), max = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())),
              format = 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your UI a function. Shiny cache's the UI portion, so it is just pulling the cached `Sys.Date()`. See https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1882

The date you are seeing is usually the last time your server was restarted.

Copied from link above:

**Turn this:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(...)
```

**into this:**

```
ui <- function(req) {
  fluidPage(...)
}
```