# Loading jquery in the last position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I offen heard that loading jquery as last element is a good idea because this way a web page loads faster. At the same time I have a script in the header which shows error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {// Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
... 
}
```

Should I move jquery loader before the script or I need to change this script some way?

Comment: `$(document)` is using JQuery .

Comment: Can you view us your html? I think you load the jquery file after you use it. Therefor the `$` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete issue stems from the fact that you execute statements that use jQuery (i.e. they execute `$`, which is a *function* in the jQuery library, also called "the jQuery function" because `jQuery` is an alias) before it is loaded.

True, it is typically recommended to [load *scripts* last](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105394/419956), but that still means the scripts have to be loaded in the correct order, with usually jQuery before your own scripts *using* jQuery.

If you *really* want to load your own scripts *before* jQuery for some reason, you need to defer its execution and have a third helper script to run it, e.g.:

```
// script.js
(function() {
  function myLibraryMainFn() {
    $('div').text('simulating work, utilizing jQuery');
  }

  window.myNamespace = {
    run: function() {
      myLibraryMainFn()
    }
  };
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Run your script now:
      window.myNamespace.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Always refer library file first(in your case jQuery), then use it next..For page load and performance add it before body end tags of your HTML