# Managing timing of a slideshow from HTML Application

Tags: html

Hello all iam trying to make an HTML application where i can manage the slide timing of each slide in a slide show HTML file Here is the code 
ANy IDea 
THank you...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!--
SlideShow v1.0
Troy Wolf <troy@troywolf.com>
Simply define your "slides" in the javascript slides[] array below.
-->
<html>
<head>
<title>SiteShow 1.0</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">


<style>
/* Change body background-color to change fade out color. */
body.siteshow { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#000000; }
#menu
{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:9pt;
display:none;
opacity:0.00;
-mozopacity:0.00;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
padding:5px;
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
border:3px dotted #999999;
}
#menu a { color:#ffffff; }
#menu a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
#title { font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:2; }
#slides { font-size:9pt; line-height:16pt; }
.button { width:60px; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:1; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var current_idx = 0;
var slides = new Array();
var menuwin;
var show_timer;
var menu_timer;
var menu;
var content;
var loaded = true;

// Define your "slides". 3 values for each are:
//      1. Duration in seconds.
//      2. Title to be used in menu.
//      3. Source URL. Can be full URI or a relative URL.
slides[1] = new Array(75, "", "main.htm");
slides[2] = new Array(180, "", "video.htm");
slides[3] = new Array(147, "", "video1.htm");
function MenuInit()
{
var html = "";
for(idx=1; idx<slides.length; idx++) {
    html += '<a href="javascript:Navigate('+idx+')">' +
        slides[idx][1] + "</a><br />\n";
}
document.getElementById("slides").innerHTML = html;
menu.style.display = "block";
}

function MenuShow()
{
clearTimeout(menu_timer);
opacity('menu', 0, 90, 500);
menu_timer = setTimeout("MenuHide()", 3500);
}

function MenuHide()
{
opacity('menu', 90, 0, 500);
}

function Pause()
{
clearTimeout(show_timer);
document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "none";
}

function Navigate(slide_idx)
{
clearTimeout(show_timer);
if (current_idx == 0) {
    if (!slide_idx) { slide_idx = 1; }
    current_idx = slide_idx;
    content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "block";
    show_timer = setTimeout("Navigate()", slides[current_idx][0]*1000);
    return;
 }

if (slide_idx) {
    current_idx = slide_idx;
    content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "none";
    return;
}

loaded = false;
current_idx++;
if ( current_idx == slides.length) { current_idx = 1; }
opacity('content', 100, 0, 500);
document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "block";
show_timer = setTimeout("Navigate()", slides[current_idx][0]*1000);
return;   
}

function opacity(id, opacStart, opacEnd, millisec)
{
//speed for each frame
var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
var timer = 0;

//determine the direction for the blending, if start and end are the same      nothing        happens
if(opacStart > opacEnd) {
    for(i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
        setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
        timer++;
    }
    if (opacEnd == 0) { setTimeout("FadeOutTrigger('"+id+"')",((timer-1) * speed));; }
    //if (opacEnd == 0) { FadeOutTrigger(id); }
 } else if(opacStart < opacEnd) {
     if (opacStart == 0) { FadeInTrigger(id); }
    for(i = opacStart; i <= opacEnd; i++)
        {
        setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
        timer++;
     }
 }
 }

 //change the opacity for different browsers
 function changeOpac(opacity, id)
 {
var object = document.getElementById(id).style;
object.opacity = (opacity / 100);
object.MozOpacity = (opacity / 100);
object.KhtmlOpacity = (opacity / 100);
object.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
}

function FadeOutTrigger(id)
{
//alert('FadeOut: '+id);
switch(id) {
case "menu":
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    break;
case "content":
    content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
    //setTimeout("opacity('content', 0, 100, 500)", 1000);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
}

function FadeInTrigger(id)
{
//alert('FadeIn: '+id);
switch(id) {
```

case "menu":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
    case "content":
        //opacity('content', 0, 100, 500);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    }

```
function FadeInContent()
{
if (!loaded) {
    opacity('content', 0, 100, 500);
    loaded = true;
}
}

function LoadTrigger()
{
//self.resizeTo(1366,768);
menu = document.getElementById('menu');
content = document.getElementById('content');
Navigate();
MenuInit();
MenuShow();
}

window.onload = LoadTrigger;

</script>

</head>
<body class="siteshow">
<center><iframe id="content" name="content" style="width:1280; height:720;"      frameborder="no" scrolling="no" menubar="no" location="no" resizable="no" status="no"   addressbar="no" src="" onmouseover="MenuShow();" onload="FadeInContent();" ></iframe>   </center>
<div id="menu">
<div id="title">SiteShow Menu</div>
<div id="slides">
</div>
<p>
         <input id="pause" class="button" style="display:block;" type="button"   value="pause" onclick="Pause()" />
    <input id="play" class="button" style="display:none;" type="button" value="play"   onclick="Navigate()" />
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can set the amount of time in seconds that the slide will show for in the js array. so your first slide looks like its set to show for 75 seconds:

slides[1] = new Array(75, "", "main.htm");

Comment: YEah sure but i dont wan to manually edit this time throught the code i want an HTML app to do that Can you help me please

Comment: one approach would be to use a define a variable using an HTML form field (this looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425469/how-to-refer-to-a-javascript-variable-in-a-value-field) and then replace the number in the array with that variable.