# How do I move or include compressed and concatenated CSS to footer in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Seems like a simple question, since you can do it with JS files, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I know for javascript things like `moveJsFromHeaderToFooter` and `includeJSFooter` exist in typoscript config, but no such setting for stylesheets.
I compress and concatenate my stylesheets as well, so the result isn't a static file either.

Comment: In general CSS inclusions should be at the most top position, while JS should placed be after whole code. Maybe that's why no such option. See [some explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517855/1066240) about that

Comment: If you determined to put styles into the footer, just don't use it by `page.includeCSS` and put it directly within your template or with `page.999` as a common text in your TypoScript template.

Comment: @biesior True, I approached my problem the wrong way. My goal is to avoid making my merged stylesheet a render blocking source and I thought I could do it like one does with scripts. It seems like I have to work with rel="preload" and some other attributes to achieve this. Unsure how to do it yet with compression and concatenation already happening... I'll see if I can find an answer to that.

Comment: Actually they should be cached in most cases and although don't know your CSS in general they shouldn't be a big problem nowadays when we have broad bandwidths everywhere. That was a clue maybe 15 years ago. Optionally you can also try to minify it.

Comment: We had a little discussion about defering CSS here https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91769

Comment: @biesior I did all of it, merge, minify, concatenate, gzip and the result is a relatively small file. However, Google Pagespeed still calls it a render blocking source. Now, there is a way to approach this here https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/ and I could change the typo3 source file to match it, but I might also wait until the feature is implemented in TYPO3.

Comment: @JonasEberle Great to see it progressing! May I ask, does f:asset.css work with concatenation? I've included some css files with f:asset to test it out, but they weren't merged with the other css files.

Comment: Offtopic: I don't use concatenation. And if I would, I would not let TYPO3 handle that...

Answer (score 2):

I am not discussing its right or not but if you want to move whole CSS to footer here is the solution:

1. Copy file `public/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html` to some location in your basic extension like `myext/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html`
2. In Template Typoscript put:

   `config.pageRendererTemplateFile = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html`
3. In `myext/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html` you see markers. Just move CSS markers you want to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The style tag is only valid in the head section. Thats why TYPO3 does not provide a move to footer option.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

So please create valid html

Comment: In my case it would be a link tag to the css file, but you're right either way since both link and style tags belong into the head tag.

Comment: If I am not wrong, one reason to move Javascript to footer is that you usually use jQuery to manipulate the DOM and you usually use `$( document ).ready(function() ...` that is executed once the page is ready, so it is useful to put it just before the end of the document

Comment: You need to take into accout <link rel=stylesheet> as well. This is allowed in <body> as well, though MDN does not recommend it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link