# Load HTML file faster in Android application

Tags: html, performance, load

By clicking on an image immediately particular HTML page should get loaded, but it is taking few seconds to get load. Please tell me how to avoid/reduce that waiting time and display page as soon as possible. Have used CSS and also modified HTML page to make it lighter but still no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizie your images using [photoshop](http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/optimizing-images-for-web-35/). If you don't Have photoshop use an [online service](http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx).

Don't use any inline CSS or JavaScript, point to external files.

E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="http://someplace.com/jxt1.js"></SCRIPT>
```

[Move your JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196702/773263) to right before the

```
</body>
```

Causing the HTML to load before the script is run.