# Best way to link to jQuery files

Tags: jquery

Is it better, in terms of site performance/speed, to link out to jquery, like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

or to put the files on the server and link to them from there instead, like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: [It's actually a good idea to do both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654918/html5-boilerplate-and-jquery) -- the CDN is probably faster, but a local backup is useful in case the CDN is down for some reason. Just be sure you [link to the specific version on the CDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn/12608285#12608285) for optimal benefit to your visitors.

Comment: which one is better for site speed?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess I would say the local server side. Would be quicker for the server to access imo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends who has the faster server, right? :)

There are a few advantages with `code.jquery.com`:

1. It's very common.  Users are likely to already have that file cached if they've been to another site that uses that file.
2. It's probably geographically load balanced.  It could load faster for users who are far away from your web server.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else mentioned, a local fallback is always a good idea, but you should also set the IE vs non-IE versions appropriately. Something simple like this should do the trick:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js""></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->

<script>
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

The first part is the conditional if for jQuery built with workarounds for older IE vs the faster, more efficient jQuery 2.0 version. This uses the Google CDN since that has both `http` and `https` versions, whereas `code.jquery.com` only has `http`. If `https` is not a concern, though, the `code.jquery.com` CDN is usually faster.

The second piece is checking if `window.jQuery` was created, and if not, use the local version.

The benefit to using a CDN version vs local version is just speed. Not only is their server bandwidth likely much (MUCH) larger than yours, most browsers have accessed that version before and have it stored in cache so the browser doesn't need to redownload it.

Comment: You have a typo on the first script tag, you double quoted it. Other than that, I'm using the exact same code :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to attach jQuery (or any library that google cdn is sharing) is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

This code links jQuery from CDN (this way is better because user could ALREADY HAVE this jQuery ver. in browser cache). After that code checks is jQuery successfully loaded (maybe CDN was down or something...) and if it's not it attaches the local version of jQuery lib to your page.

This code is used in [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using a CDN (such as `code.jquery.com`) will be able to deliver the files to your users quicker than your own servers - that's what they exist for!

You may also want to consider using a copy on your own server as a fallback if for any reason the CDN fails.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are referring to library through a remote URL while in second case it's locally available on the server.

So it depends on many factors. Finally its about how far your end user is from the jquery url. User could be closer to your host or jquery host as well. Also it will depend on which one is serving the request most efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

i prefer using googleapis:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

here is [why.](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)