# JsFiddle not executing on ready

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I'm following a [guy's example](https://jsfiddle.net/9upkgsLz/) fiddling but despite him added the jQuery on the left, the script doesn't execute on run.

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("hjk");
});
```

I can't ask him, so I wonder what simple thing I can be missing.

I've checked that the syntax is correct on jQuery's page [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). The link to jQuery library is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18702587/1525840).

Comment: You have to add jquery library there. https://jsfiddle.net/9upkgsLz/1/

Comment: It's added on the left pane. It's from the link in my question. What else should be added?

Comment: the link you have included points to 404 error (https://jsfiddle.net/9upkgsLz/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js) you most likely missed the first `/` of the `//` you were supposed to copy.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Strange. When I click on the link to js.min on the left, I get the text file on the screen. It's [this link](//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)... I removed it and pasted again and it seems to solve the issue. Weird...

Comment: Look at error thrown in browser console. It clearly shows that `$` is undefined and also path is incorrect in your demo. Always check console for errors!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the Javascript button on the top right of the javascript content box and choose jquery as framework, you can also choose between onDomready and onLoad. No need to manually add the jquery js on the left pane.

Also the js code inside the javascript content box shouldn't be wrapped in anything like `$(document).ready` since jsfiddle already does that.