# onChange() not working on server but works fine on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, dependencies, onchange, jsfiddle

Compare the code on

jsfiddle

HTML

```
<select name="client_select" id="client_select">
<option value="Name not listed">Name not listed</option>
<option value="1">abc company</option>
</select>
<span id="client_add"><input type="text" name ="" value="field1"/></span>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("client_select").onchange = 
function (e) {
if (this.value == 'Name not listed') {
    document.getElementById("client_add").style.display="";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("client_add").style.display="none";    
    }
};
```

to

my site

```
<script>
document.getElementById("client_select").onchange = 
function (e) {
    if (this.value == 'Name not listed') {
        document.getElementById("client_add").style.display="";
    } else {
document.getElementById("client_add").style.display="none";    
    }
};
</script>
<select name="client_select" id="client_select">
<option value="Name not listed">Name not listed</option>
    <option value="1">abc company</option>
</select>
<span id="client_add"><input type="text" name ="" value="field1"/></span>
```

## Solution:

Run javascript after elements have been loaded into the clients DOM.

#### Do one of the following:

- Load  javascript AFTER html elements
- Use a onLoad() to wrap script
- With jQuery use $( document ).ready(function() { }

Comment: Am I missing any dependencies that jsfiddle has by default? I checked and jsfiddle doesn't seem to be including anything.

Comment: The object wasn't loaded in the DOM when I was trying to find it with Javascript. Solution script after elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is not available when you're trying to use it, as it hasn't been loaded in the DOM yet.

Move the script after the elements

```
<select name="client_select" id="client_select">
    <option value="Name not listed">Name not listed</option>
    <option value="1">abc company</option>
</select>
<span id="client_add"><input type="text" name ="" value="field1"/></span>

<script>
    document.getElementById("client_select").onchange = function(e) {
        if (this.value == 'Name not listed') {
            document.getElementById("client_add").style.display = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("client_add").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
</script>
```

I would also encourage the use of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to wrap your script in a `window.onload` function like:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Do things here...
};
```

Or if jQuery is available:

```
$(function(){
    // Do things here...
});
```

Comment: yes thank you, also even better with jquery $( document ).ready(function() { }

Comment: ^^^ not really -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file