# Javascript in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with the JavaScript in bootstrap. It working fine for css,but when i use javascript like modal or tooltips, it won't show. I don't know what went wrong, i've downloaded all the source code from http://getbootstrap.com/ and put

```
//css bootstrap
<link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

//js bootstrap
<script src="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So, what should i add/configure more?

Comment: Do you have jquery included in your JS?  Pretty sure bootstrap needs it.

Comment: Hi @Nadia. Bootstrap should not be the cause of your problem. Please post some of your javascript code and tell us specifically what is wrong. We cannot debug code we can't see.

Comment: Please add any JavaScript console errors, it would help others to debug this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23476758/3300831

Comment: @shredmill yes i have it, it's in ../js/tests/vendor/jquery.js folder.

Comment: @NadiaPerry it doesn't do anygood to have it on your server if you don't include it in your page.

Comment: @adelphia i know Bootstrap is not the problem, it's my problem because i'm too silly and i can't even get this to work. Wait i post you guys the code i'm doing

Comment: @adelphia so i need to include `jquery.js` into my page? But it says on the startup page you only need to put `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Bootstrap will work fine without the .js files. They're only there to suppliment the CSS. However if you choose to use `bootstrap.js` you  will also need to include jQuery. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shredmil mentioned above, Bootstrap does require jQuery. Make sure it's included ABOVE `bootstrap.min.js`.

```
//css bootstrap
<link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

//js bootstrap
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: okay....so that's all the problem? I've been having this problem for week and that's all? Anyway, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: you're very welcomed. props to shredmil who said it first. :)