# Jquery checkbox selected issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying select all "area" under one "Zone" using Jquery. But unfortunately its not working. Can you tell me what I'm wrong with this ?

```
<script>
$('#central_all').click(function () {    
    $(':checkbox.checkItem').prop('checked', this.checked);    
 });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="pre_central" value="" id="central_all"/> <strong>Central</strong> <br/>   

<input type="checkbox" name="pre_marina_esplanade" value="" class="checkItem"/> Marina, Esplanade, Suntec
<input type="checkbox" name="pre_raffles_place" value=""  class="checkItem"/> Raffles Place 
<input type="checkbox" name="pre_chinatown" value=""  class="checkItem"/> Chinatown
```

I want if Central checkbox is click then all other checkbox will be selected which have class name `checkItem`. But it's not selected :(

Comment: it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/6J9zC/ ?

Comment: its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/8/

Comment: Yes I see but why it's not working in my PC. Strange !!!

Comment: Oh It's working now. The jquery code was above the html. Now it's bellow the html code. Working fine :)

Comment: @Burak can you tell me, Is it important to place the Jquery code bellow all html code ?

Comment: @Shibbir see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file

Comment: @Burak Thanks for this link. It's very helpful.