# Where to place the script code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Many times I have come across javascript script includes some of them are placed in the head portion and some are placed at the end of the body. And in some cases of jQuery I have seen the same. Can anyone tell me what is the difference and significant between putting scripts in the head or at the end of the body?

Comment: Did you try searching before you asked this question? This has been asked **many** times before.... [Where to place Javascript in a HTML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file)

Comment: there is no such difference, it's upto you

Comment: @AmitSoni it's different, in HTML parser you have a recursive descent parser; top-down parser

Comment: @AmitSoni There is a [difference](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), it does matter, it's not just personal preference.

Comment: @AmitSoni: Obviously, it matters. There's a reason why we prefer to place it at the end of body.

Comment: Please do some search before asking. It has been asked many times. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo recommends to put all scripts at the bottom of your page.

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads.
> The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more
> than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images
> from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur
> in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't
> start any other downloads, even on different hostnames...[Read
> More](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

It is often seen that jQuery is placed at the top, this is to avoid any dependacy issues that you might face in your custom code.