# What is the difference between below two code snippets?

Tags: javascript

a)

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>An example for object method</title>
            <script src= "js/test.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Here is an example for object method</h3>
            <p id = "demo"></p>
         
       </body>
</html>
```

b)

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>An example for object method</title>
        
     </head>
     <body>
         <h3>Here is an example for object method</h3>
         <p id = "demo"></p>
         <script src= "js/test.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

How will these two blocks of code differ while loading a webpage? The first block is not loading the JavaScript file, while the second one is running fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place Javascript in a HTML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

In the second snippet, the `js/test.js` code does not run until AFTER the HTML has been loaded.  This allows it to directly access anything in the DOM.  For example if that script does `var obj = document.getElementById("demo");`, it will return the demo DOM object.

In the first snippet, the HTML of the page is not yet available when `js/test.js` runs.  If the script does `var obj = document.getElementById("demo");`, it will return `null` because that DOM object is not yet available (has not yet been loaded).

See this answer ([pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)) for a more in depth discussion of this topic and an option for how to make code in the first option "wait" to execute until the DOM is ready.