# Lightbox Not Working Onto (Any)Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lightbox

I watched a tutorial on a simple lightbox, and I am trying to figure out why it is not working for me. I am using http://lokeshdhakar.com/ version of the lightbox.

I do not know what the issue is. When I type it through the text editor I am using it just opens up the image in a new window. But just now in the code.io , it opened it up as the proper lightbox. I am so confused on what is happening.

Here is my code.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Fine Art</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="styles5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <link href="fineart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    
family=Roboto:400,100,400italic,500,900,300,500italic,900italic"  
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<h1 class="fineart"> B &amp; W Photo </h1>
  <div id="page"><!--beginning of sidebar-->
<div id="sidebar">
    <div><a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/></a>  
</div>
    <div>
    <ul class="sb">
        <li ><a href="index.html"> Home</a> </li>
        <li ><a href="about.html"> About</a> </li>
        <li ><a  href="works.html"> Works</a> </li>
        <li ><a  href="resume.html"> Resume</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    </div>




    <script  
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
    });

});

</script>

</div><!--end of sidebar-->

<div class="container-a4">
    <ul class="caption-style-4">
        <li>
            <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2re64y0.jpg" alt="blur">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                  <h1><a href="http://i63.tinypic.com/9lhaj9.jpg" data- 
lightbox="photos">Blur</a></h1>
                  <p> Photo Series </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(here's the rest)
http://codepen.io/kasiariele/pen/jbjVgr

Like I said, I'm not sure why its working in the site editor, but when I save and refresh onto the browser it opens the image on a new page instead of the lightbox. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order your javascript libraries correctly.

You are loading `lightbox.min.js` **before** loading `jquery.min.js` (which is a dependency for how you are using lightbox).

Here is a direct quote from the [lightbox website](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started).

> If you already use jQuery on your page, make sure it is loaded **before** lightbox.js. jQuery 1.7 or greater is required.

You should also [load all of your `scripts` together right before your `</body>` closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file), like so:

```
<script  
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
</script>
```