# Google map in a bootstrap tab - specific code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

The map doesn't load properly when using bootstrap tabs. The solution is to resize the map upon clicking the specific tab. I have been fooling with this for way too long. I have used other solutions I found on stack but I have no idea why its still not working.

Here is all of my code. I apologize for the sloppiness. I usually go back and pretty it up when I have finished the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Oswald|Titillium Web|Roboto  ">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var myLatLng = {lat: 64.8370761, lng: -147.697845};
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: "Nelson's Photography"
        });
      }

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
            initialize();
        });

    </script>
  </head>



  <body>
    <nav class="navbardos navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/images/titlegraphic.jpg" class="logo"></a>
        </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-navdos">
            <li><a class="number">(907)452-3116</a></li>
            <li><a>606 Bentley Drive | Fairbanks, AK</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="tab-content">

      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="/images/10x10reflect-lg.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Music Production Studio</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="/images/11830247_10207115344978900_1142161344_n.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Beat Gallery</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Listen</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="/images/TMPstudio.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="width: 600px;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Studio Services</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Check-It Out</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
      </div>

      <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
        <img src="images/entry.jpg" id="AboutPic1">
        <h1></h1>
        <p id="lead">
            Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> 
            All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="services" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>FUCK me</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="portfolio" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>FUCK me</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="contact-content">
        <h1>We're looking forward to<br> 
            hearing from you!</h1><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Phone Number:</h2>
        <h2>907-452-3116</h2><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Email:</h2>
        <h2>email</h2><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Address:</h2>
        <h2>
            Nelson's Professional Photography<br>
            address<br>
            Fairbanks, Alaska 99701<br>
        </h2>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #777
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;


}

.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #336699;
    border: 0px;
    height: 51px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

/*.nav.nav-pills{


}*/
.nav.nav-pills li a{
    color: white;
    font-family: Roboto, Titillium Web, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    padding-left: 76px;
    padding-right: 76px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}
.nav-pills li a:hover{
      color: grey;

}



.navbardos.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top { 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    border: 0px;
    height: 120px;
}

.nav.navbar-navdos{
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    width: 200px;
}

.nav.navbar-navdos li a{

    padding:0px;
    color: white;

}

.nav.navbar-navdos li a:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

.number {
    font-size: 30px;

}
.logo {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -130px;
}

#home{
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;

}

#about{
    margin-top: 150px;
    width:100%
}

#services{
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#portfolio{
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#contact{
    font-family: Titillium Web, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:  #E8E8E8;
}

#contact-content{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 176px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#map {
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;  
    width: 550px;
    height: 400px;
}

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  height: 500px;
}

.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary {
  background-color: #FF9900 ; 
}

.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #B22400    ; 
}
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
  background-image:none;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: You need to change `data-toggle="pill"` to `data-toggle="tab"`, see the updated example Snippets (2 and 3).

You can try simply using:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  initialize();
});
```

to initialize.

See working example Snippet.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 64.8370761,
    lng: -147.697845
  };
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Nelson's Photography"
  });
}

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  initialize();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  max-width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Home
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        About
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="services" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Services
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Portfolio
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Map
      </div>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Updated Code: Example 2

```js
 function initialize() {
   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
   var myLatLng = {
     lat: 64.8370761,
     lng: -147.697845
   };
   var mapOptions = {
     center: myLatLng,
     zoom: 16,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     title: "Nelson's Photography"
   });
 }

 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
   initialize();
 });
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #777
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #336699;
  border: 0px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
/*.nav.nav-pills{


}*/

.nav.nav-pills li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto, Titillium Web, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 76px;
  padding-right: 76px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
.navbardos.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0px;
  height: 120px;
}
.nav.navbar-navdos {
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  width: 200px;
}
.nav.navbar-navdos li a {
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
}
.nav.navbar-navdos li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
.number {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.logo {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: -130px;
}
#home {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
#about {
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 100%
}
#services {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
#portfolio {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
#contact {
  font-family: Titillium Web, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #E8E8E8;
}
#contact-content {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 176px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#map {
  margin-left: 650px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}
/* Carousel base class */

.carousel {
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */

.carousel-caption {
  height: 500px;
}
.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #B22400;
}
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */

.carousel .item {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbardos navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/images/titlegraphic.jpg" class="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-navdos">
      <li><a class="number">(907)452-3116</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>606 Bentley Drive | Fairbanks, AK</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="/images/10x10reflect-lg.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Music Production Studio</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="/images/11830247_10207115344978900_1142161344_n.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Beat Gallery</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Listen</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="/images/TMPstudio.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="width: 600px;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Studio Services</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Check-It Out</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
    <img src="images/entry.jpg" id="AboutPic1">
    <h1></h1>
    <p id="lead">
      Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>FUCK me</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="portfolio" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>FUCK me</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="contact-content">
      <h1>We're looking forward to<br> 
            hearing from you!</h1>
      <br>
      <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Phone Number:</h2>
      <h2>907-452-3116</h2>
      <br>
      <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Email:</h2>
      <h2>email</h2>
      <br>
      <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Address:</h2>
      <h2>
            Nelson's Professional Photography<br>
            address<br>
            Fairbanks, Alaska 99701<br>
        </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Example 3

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 64.8370761,
    lng: -147.697845
  };
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Nelson's Photography"
  });
}

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  initialize();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar.navbar-top,
.navbar.navbar-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-bottom .navbar-nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-bottom .navbar-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-bottom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: -24px;
  }
  .navbar-top {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-top,
  .navbar-bottom {
    border: none;
  }
}
.carousel,
.item,
.active,
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Carousel base class */

.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */

.carousel .carousel-caption {
  height: 500px;
}
.carousel .btn.btn-lg.btn-primary {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}
.carousel .btn.btn-lg.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #B22400;
}
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */

.carousel .carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel .carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33.33%;
}
.carousel .carousel-control.right,
.carousel .carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
}
.contact-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 65px 15px 15px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 500px;
}
.contact-content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.contact-content h2:nth-child(even) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    top: 10%;
  }
  #map {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .contact-content {
    top: 145px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px 15px 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .contact-content h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .contact-content h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/f00">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">+! (907)-452-3116</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">606 Bentley Drive | Fairbanks, AK</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">BRAND</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="http://placehold.it/2500x1000/ff0" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Music Production Studio</h1>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="http://placehold.it/2500x1000/000" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Beat Gallery</h1>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Listen</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="http://placehold.it/2500x1000/444" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Studio Services</h1>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Check-It Out</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/f00" id="AboutPic1">
    <p id="lead">
      Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>FUCK me</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="portfolio" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>FUCK me</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
      <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="contact-content">
      <h1>We're looking forward to<br> 
                    hearing from you!</h1>
      <h2>Phone Number:</h2>
      <h2>907-452-3116</h2>
      <h2>Email:</h2>
      <h2>email</h2>
      <h2>Address:</h2>
      <h2>Nelson's Professional Photography<br>
                    Fairbanks, Alaska 99701<br>
                </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I attempted to implement your advice and it still is not working.  Would you be willing to check my full code? Perhaps I am making a really dumb mistake somewhere else in the code...

Comment: Yes, if you're still having problems definitely post more code.

Comment: Thank You!! I will edit the post to include all the code.

Comment: I tried that before. I don't know man It's still not working. I even tried posting you're original snippets into my code editor/previewer just to see if it worked and they don't.  Then I tried it in multiple online code previewers.

Comment: I know that sounds stupid because its working right here. I guess I am a lost cause.

Comment: Are you still loading all the google maps js in the document head? If so move them down to the bottom of the document with the rest if your js.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that directly in my update, I meant to. Glad its working for you.

Comment: You know whats funny @vanburen ? I think i tried moving them all into the head at one point but not into the bottom of the body.

Comment: Hey it happens, we've all been there at one point or another.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the difference is between having them in the head compared to the body?

Comment: It basically comes down how browsers download page components/assets like images, css, js, etc. if your js starts executing before it has any html to reference because the document isn't ready yet, you'll see problems similar to your map not loading. See this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file