# jquery ajax: Unexpected Token & function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, api

This is my first attempt at javascript trying to call to API and I'm getting the following in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected Token ,

> Uncaught Reference Error: AjaxCall is not defined.

[I just posted here today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297094/html-button-not-calling-function?noredirect=1#comment60219110_36297094), edited the answer to my liking, and got more errors.

Thanks for helping!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="AjaxCall()">Click Here</button>
        <p id="Data"></p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var vToken = "MyToken";
            var Target_URL = "MyUrl";

            function AjaxCall() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: Target_URL,
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization',
                        'Bearer ' + vToken
                    },
                    method: 'GET'
                    success: alert(result)
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your completed code. Should work fine with right urls and headers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head> 
        <body>

        <button onclick="AjaxCall()">Click Here</button>
        <p id="Data"></p>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var vToken = "MyToken";
        var Target_URL = "MyUrl";


        function AjaxCall(){
         $.ajax({
            url: Target_URL,
            headers: {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + vToken
            },
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
          }); 

        }
        </script>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: I'll be testing this shortly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple syntax error in this section of your code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Target_URL,
    headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + vToken
    },
    method: 'GET'
    success: alert(result)
});
```

This line:

```
'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + vToken
```

ought to be

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + vToken
```

with a colon `:` rather than a comma `,`. That's what the `Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected Token ,` error meant.

---

Also, you're missing a comma after `'GET'` (thanks to [@char](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5875951/char)):

```
method: 'GET'
```

should be

```
method: 'GET',
```

Comment: Also missing a comma after the `GET`

Comment: Thank you. That answers the unexpected token issue

Answer (score 0):

```
         something wrong with your Authorization params, please keep headers correct
         $.ajax({
            url: Target_URL,
            headers: {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + vToken
            },
            method: 'GET'
            success: alert(result)
          });
```

Comment: It's a cURL to Ajax conversion based from the this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Comment: success should be a callback function, where result is passed as parameter. Please check my answer.