# Can an HTML5 notification fire from an inactive tab and play an audio alert?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-notifications

Say, you want to play a beep.mp3 on the hour so you wrote JavaScript code that does this, which is not all that hard. But when the user switches to another tab, and your page soon becomes living in an inactive tab, you won't hear those audio alerts any more.

Is there a remedy for this?

Answer (score 0):

If we include audio in HTML then we can play by using JavaScript, even if the browser tab is inactive.

```
<body>
    <audio id="beep" src="audio source file" preload="auto" ></audio>

    <script>
        function playBeep() {
           document.getElementById("beep").play();
        }
        playBeep();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does `<script></script>` belongs in `<body></body>`?

Comment: `<script>` can be written in the `<head>`, `<body>` or in external file, but is better to know the implications, you cant find a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: @Peter Mortensen You can find good answer here [where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file)