# JS is not working

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why simple code is not working is my browser.

```
    <head>
     <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../static/js/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
     $("#totalCart").html("99,75");
    </script>  
   </head>

<body>
 <div id="totalCart">Total </div>
</body>
```

when I start this code in Chrome I see nothing, why?

Comment: Use document ready handler, read https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: check browser console . if any error here you find the error

Comment: Hit F12 and go to the Console and Network tabs. Any errors? Also, your script is run before the element in your HTML is created. Either put the Javascript at the bottom of the file (before `</body>`) or use jQuery's [`.ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23476758/2008111

Comment: @taposghosh — There won't be an error. jQuery fails silently.

Comment: @caramba — That's a red herring since all the discussion is about performance and not the problem the OP is experiencing. (And it isn't great for performance either since it prevents parallel downloading).

Comment: browser in view page source check all your js file loading correctly or not

Comment: @taposghosh — You seem to be confusing the page source code with the Network tag in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a selection before **DOM** is loaded.

The good practice is to include all **script** at the **end** of your body.

Or you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
<script>
$("#totalCart").html("99,75");
</script>
```

just before

```
</body>
```

---

**Explanation:**

For jQuery to grab an element via `$("#totalCart")` - and, likewise, for non-library javascript to grab an element via `document.getElementById('totalCart')` - that element has to first exist.

In your original structure, the script runs as soon as it is parsed - but this happens before the element is parsed... effectively, at the moment the script runs, the element does not yet exist.

By the time the element is parsed and does exist, the script has already run and it is not invoked a second time.

If you place the `<script>` at the very end of the document (just before `<body>`) then all elements will already have been parsed by the browser rendering engine and they will exist.