# Inserting HTML fragments without an element container in React

Tags: reactjs

Our React app uses universal rendering. The html/body/head elements of the page are generated server-side using a React component. Normally, we can create things like `<script>` and `<link>` elements in our `<head>` just fine via JSX. Unfortunately, things got tricky once we started needing to insert third-party HTML fragments. These fragments are essentially a string like `'<script src="some/url.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="/some/css">'`. Normally, HTML fragments can be injected into some element container via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but there *are* no container elements for the `<head>` of an HTML document. This has forced us to either:

1. *Parse* the HTML fragments (no easy task) and convert them into React elements
2. Abandon JSX and build all our head content as one big concatenated/templated string

Is there any way in React to inject an HTML fragment into a document *without* a container element?

Comment: Do they have to go inside the head?

Comment: That's a good question; I know that links typically go in the head. Has that changed in recent years?

Comment: I don't think link is officially kosher, but I've done style tags in the body to load external css.  Could also just use vanilla js server side to do it.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: @Jacob If you wan't them loaded before the site is rendered they go to the head. If you wan't them loaded after the first render, they go at the end of the body.
Scripts therefore often go in the body.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-an-html-file

Comment: Can't [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) be used for this?

Comment: @pavindu not if you have HTML strings; you can't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a combination of [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to set the `<head>` at a component level and [Interweave](https://milesj.gitbook.io/interweave/) to inject/parse the HTML without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` could achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: `Interweave` does look like it supports this scenario with its `Markup` component, which you can wrap in a fragment. Looks like that option came out April 2018.