# Why Calling Jquery At Head Of Page Solve Most Of My Problems?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I examine HTMl5- Bootstrap templates, I see that, Jquery and the other javascript plugins are added at the bottom of the page. There is no problem, template works regulary.

But when I try to add some third party javascript plugin (forexample Floating-WhatsApp-Message-Button), surprise! It doesnt work even it based on Jquery.

So I try many and many things. But mostly this solve my problem: Moving Jquery.js calling tag inside to head tag.

I can't understand that. What is my sin? Is it a normal solution? Then why jquery.js tag is at the bottom of page in regular templates?

Comment: As long as your *plugin* `script src=` is *after* the jquery `script src=`, it doesn't (for functionality) matter where it is.   As long as you don't have any `<script>` (without `src=` and containing jquery code) *before* the jquery src=, you'll be fine.

Comment: Because scripts tags are read and parsed in order. Putting scripts that depend on scripts that aren't loaded yet fail. You're asking for bicycles before wheels have been invented.

Comment: There's plenty of answers/discussions regarding putting scripts in head vs at the end of body (on SO and off).   In summary: put in the head so that it's ready for your page / put at the end so it doesn't hold up rendering of your page while it parses the js.   Modern browsers cache *parsed* js, so if you're using a CDN or multiple pages, it will only be a "hit" on the first load.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to place JavaScript in an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-an-html-file) (and numerous linked answers from that one)

Comment: @freedomn-m I dont think this question is about whether to put at bottom or top of body/head. I think it misunderstanding dependency load order.

Comment: @zero298 I completely agree with you (upvoted your comment) but didn't want to reiterate what you said.  I went with the "why is jquery tag at the bottom [normally]?" part of the question which is pretty much the only actual question, despite it not being what's really asked - in order to find a question to vote-close it against :)  (otherwise it'll probably just get left)